# Enabling and disabling all the child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this issue with enabling and disabling section of fields if other section of fields have specific value.
Consider [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/RUR9c/4/) for html code.
**Conditions are**

1. If all the fields of `partA` are selected as `No`, then enable `partB`.
2. If all the fields of `partB` are selected as `No`, then enable `partC`.

**Try 1**

First I tried disable elements of PartB and PartC which did not work.

```
$(function () {
   $('.group').attr('name','partB').find('input').attr('disable', true);
   $('.group').attr('name','partC').find('input').attr('disable', true);                        
});
```

I am not sure how would make sure if all the child elements are selected as `No` in a `group` div.

Comment: where are you stuck???

Comment: A `<label>` can control **only one** element.

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav not the downvoter, but please, next time try to immediately provide an example of what you have tried, it'll help not only us to start from somewhere, but also to spot and point out your errors. Helps in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/AyuvEHi/12/edit)

Having this HTML:

```
<div class="group" id="partA">
    <span> PART A</span><br/>
    Option 1
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1"  value="option1"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios1"  value="option2"/>No
    <br />
    Option 2
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2"  value="option1"/>Yes
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios2"  value="option2"/>No
</div>
```

jQ:

```
$(function () {

  $('#partB, #partC').find('input').prop('disabled', true);

  function testChecked(){
    var $par = $(this).closest('.group');
    var $rad2 = $par.find('[value="option2"]');
    var allNo = $rad2.filter(':checked').length == $rad2.length;
    $par.next('.group').find(':radio').prop('disabled', !allNo);
    if(!allNo){
      $par.nextAll('.group').find(':radio').prop({'disabled':true, 'checked':false});
    }
  } 

  $('.group :radio').change(testChecked);

});
```

<sup>The above will work also for more than 2 radio groups per `.group`</sup>

**Your errors:**

`"disable", "true"` should be `"disabled", "true"`
`<label>` can control only **one** inner element (so I removed it.)
`<div>` afaik is not supposed to have a `name` attribute (so I assigned an `ID`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one problem. `PartB` and `PartC` are values of the name attributes. Would `$('.group').attr('name', 'partB, partC').find('input')` work?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav :) you're welcome! Please give me an official documentation that says that `DIV` can have an `name` attribute. If you did not build the HTML, ask than the one who did *"How you plan to validate this."*

Comment: @HimanshuYadav `$('.group').attr('name', 'partB, partC').find('input')` it's invalid jQuery usage. The way you're using `.attr()` is **assign** instead of using `attr` as selector like `$(".group[name='partB'], .group[name='partC']")` which will result (read my comment above) in a really unprofessional thing to do.